# How to serialize / deserialize correct a BST(generic type) - implementation(separate class or subclass)

Tags: java

What would be the right way of  serialize/deserialze a BST(generic type) I mean I'm thinking i should write a `class Serialize` which contains all the methods over a my generic container, but what if I make a subclass in my container which contains the serialize class? which would be the proper way of doing it?(java like)

Must the serialisation class be a independet class or it can be a subclass for the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serialize a Java class you should:

1. Implement the Serializable interface
2. Make sure all the member variables of your class can be serialized

If you just have a simple data type comprised of primitives, this is as simple as adding "implements Serializable" to your class.

More details about implementing Serializable can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

An example of serialization and deserialization can be found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm).